# How to debug a cpp file that's part of a so file in the software?

Tags: linux, debugging, dynamic-linking, gdb, static-linking

So I have this software which has multiple .so files. For one of the so file and I made some changes to the code but I want to see the line by line execution of file present in the so file.

Just to give a reference while using visual studio we can attach the code to the process that is using the dll file and then once it gets attached we put breakpoints in the file we want to debug and step over to go to the next line.

How can I achieve the same on Linux machine?
Is there any hack that would help me?

I have a software that uses so files and that so files has multiple cpp files as part of its build and I want to debug a file present in that so file.

Comment: You’ve tagged your question [tag:gdb]; isn’t that an answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions looks like a better place to ask.

Comment: But I don't know how to achieve the same using gdb, I used gdb long back for debugging stand alone files with a int main in it. But since now scenario has changed I don't know how to achieve the same

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I know when I ll ask on stackoverflow moderators will redirect me here

Comment: Have you already done that?

Comment: @StephenKitt could you please help me out with the exact commands

Comment: Can you give us a small code sample that shows how your program accesses the shared libraries? Gdb should work fine if the shared libraries are referenced in the ELF dynamic section of the main executable, or if they're accessed using `dlopen`. As with the main executable, you need to compile and link the shared libraries with the -g option in order to have line number information available.